# Using a variable in jQuery contains not working

Tags: jquery, html

```
   $("#whoToFollow").on("click", "p", function() {
    const text = $(this).text()
   $("div:not(:contains(' + text + '))").remove()
  });
```

I want to remove any divs which does not contain the text in the p tag that was clicked. The above code works if I replace (' + text + ') with the exact text ('david') but does not work when using the text variable. What am I missing here?

Comment: try `$("div:not(:contains('" + text + "'))").remove()`  You have to escape the `"` to include your variable

Answer (score 1):

Add double quotes in your jquery selector...

```
 $("#whoToFollow").on("click", "p", function() {
    const text = $(this).text()
   $("div:not(:contains('" + text + "'))").remove()
  });
```